# Fluentd not pushing logs to Elastic Search after redeployment

Tags: fluentd

After a redeployment of Fluentd cluster the logs are not pushed to Elastic Search for a while and sometimes it takes hours to get the logs finally.

My config:

```
<source>
  @type systemd
  path /run/log/journal
  matches [{ "_SYSTEMD_UNIT": "docker.service" }]
  tag docker
  read_from_head true
</source>

<filter docker>
  @type record_transformer
  enable_ruby true
  <record>
    severity log
  </record>
</filter>

<match docker>
  @type elasticsearch
  host elasticsearch
  port ****
  scheme http
  request_timeout 30s
  http_backend_excon_nonblock false
  suppress_type_name true
  index_name test-%Y%m%d
  type_name docker-fluentd
   logstash_format true
  logstash_prefix test
  reconnect_on_error true
  reload_on_failure true
  reload_connections false
<buffer>
    @type file
    path /fluentd/log/elastic-buffer
    flush_thread_count 8
    flush_interval 1s
    chunk_limit_size 32M
    queue_limit_length 4
    flush_mode interval
    retry_max_interval 30
    retry_forever true
  </buffer>
</match>
```

I get the following errors in the logs:

```
parsing config file is succeeded path="fluent.conf"
2021-03-23 13:23:51 +0000 [info]: gem 'fluent-plugin-concat' version '2.4.0'
2021-03-23 13:23:51 +0000 [info]: gem 'fluent-plugin-dedot_filter' version '1.0.0'
2021-03-23 13:23:51 +0000 [info]: gem 'fluent-plugin-detect-exceptions' version '0.0.13'
2021-03-23 13:23:51 +0000 [info]: gem 'fluent-plugin-elasticsearch' version '4.3.3'
2021-03-23 13:23:51 +0000 [info]: gem 'fluent-plugin-grok-parser' version '2.6.2'
2021-03-23 13:23:51 +0000 [info]: gem 'fluent-plugin-json-in-json-2' version '1.0.2'
2021-03-23 13:23:51 +0000 [info]: gem 'fluent-plugin-kubernetes_metadata_filter' version '2.6.0'
2021-03-23 13:23:51 +0000 [info]: gem 'fluent-plugin-multi-format-parser' version '1.0.0'
2021-03-23 13:23:51 +0000 [info]: gem 'fluent-plugin-prometheus' version '1.8.5'
2021-03-23 13:23:51 +0000 [info]: gem 'fluent-plugin-record-modifier' version '2.1.0'
2021-03-23 13:23:51 +0000 [info]: gem 'fluent-plugin-rewrite-tag-filter' version '2.4.0'
2021-03-23 13:23:51 +0000 [info]: gem 'fluent-plugin-systemd' version '1.0.2'
2021-03-23 13:23:51 +0000 [info]: gem 'fluentd' version '1.12.0'
2021-03-23 13:23:51 +0000 [warn]: both of Plugin @id and path for <storage> are not specified. Using on-memory store.
2021-03-23 13:23:51 +0000 [info]: using configuration file: <ROOT>


 
2021-03-23 13:23:51 +0000 [info]: starting fluentd-1.12.0 pid=8 ruby="2.6.6"
2021-03-23 13:23:51 +0000 [info]: spawn command to main:  cmdline=["/usr/local/bin/ruby", "-Eascii-8bit:ascii-8bit", "/fluentd/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/bin/fluentd", "-c", "/fluentd/etc/fluent.conf", "-p", "/fluentd/plugins", "--gemfile", "/fluentd/Gemfile", "-r", "/fluentd/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/fluent-plugin-elasticsearch-4.3.3/lib/fluent/plugin/elasticsearch_simple_sniffer.rb", "--under-supervisor"]
2021-03-23 13:23:52 +0000 [info]: adding filter pattern="docker" type="record_transformer"
2021-03-23 13:23:52 +0000 [info]: adding match pattern="docker" type="elasticsearch"
2021-03-23 13:23:52 +0000 [info]: adding source type="systemd"
2021-03-23 13:23:52 +0000 [warn]: #0 both of Plugin @id and path for <storage> are not specified. Using on-memory store.
2021-03-23 13:23:52 +0000 [info]: #0 starting fluentd worker pid=16 ppid=8 worker=0
2021-03-23 13:23:52 +0000 [info]: #0 fluentd worker is now running worker=0
2021-03-23 13:26:57 +0000 [warn]: #0 failed to flush the buffer. retry_time=0 next_retry_seconds=2021-03-23 13:26:58 +0000 chunk="5be342287e58bb254e5c2b20d8deb496" error_class=Fluent::Plugin::ElasticsearchOutput::RecoverableRequestFailure error="could not push logs to Elasticsearch cluster ({:host=>\"elasticsearch\", :port=>9200, :scheme=>\"http\"}): Rejected Elasticsearch due to es_rejected_execution_exception"
    failed to flush the buffer. retry_time=0 next_retry_seconds=2021-03-23 13:06:00 +0000 chunk="5be33d724d11145f2605b016a9e6cd48" error_class=Fluent::Plugin::ElasticsearchOutput::RecoverableRequestFailure error="could not push logs to Elasticsearch cluster ({:host=>\"elasticsearch\", :port=>9200, :scheme=>\"http\"}): [429] {\"error\":{\"root_cause\":[{\"type\":\"es_rejected_execution_exception\",\"reason\":\"rejected execution of coordinating operation [coordinating_and_primary_bytes=44407079, replica_bytes=0, all_bytes=44407079, coordinating_operation_bytes=10894804, max_coordinating_and_primary_bytes=53687091]\"}],\"type\":\"es_rejected_execution_exception\",\"reason\":\"rejected execution of coordinating operation [coordinating_and_primary_bytes=44407079, replica_bytes=0, all_bytes=44407079, coordinating_operation_bytes=10894804, max_coordinating_and_primary_bytes=53687091]\"},\"status\":429}"
```

I have tried few solutions found while googling but none of them resolves my issue.

Elastic search UI:

[elasticsearch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2B3NB.jpg)

Added more logs

I get the below error when trying to modify filter to get value from existing field

[fluentlogs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7AP5b.jpg)

Comment: Please add the startup logs along with all the errors. Where's ES hosted? The error shows that ES is at `elasticsearch:9200`, is that correct?

Comment: @Azeem yes thats correct

Comment: Are you able to connect to it via `telnet` or `curl`?

Comment: @Azeem i have not checked that.

Comment: You should check the connectivity to ES first and then see if the fluentd is able to establish that connection as well. The retries are normal but they eventually succeed depending on the network latency and the configuration.

Comment: @Azeem could you guide on how to o that

Comment: `curl elasticsearch:9200`

Comment: It seems that the old log files are read again after redeployment and that why the whole process takes endless time and now it doesnt load new logs at all; is there a way to prevent reading old files and read only the new log files.

Comment: You need to show your `<source>` config as well.

Comment: Added source info

Comment: Remove: `read_from_head true` and test again.

Comment: Removed and redeployed but the logs are already coming in. I would like that once redeployed the fluentd is  started and logs atart when some action happens and not from previous log files

Comment: From the [config](https://github.com/fluent-plugin-systemd/fluent-plugin-systemd#input-plugin-configuration), it looks like you need to configure `matches`. In your config, it's already configured but I think you need to further optimize it for your use-case. See: https://github.com/fluent-plugin-systemd/fluent-plugin-systemd/blob/master/docs/matching.md.

Comment: Can you make it more clear as to how i can achieve that

Comment: is there a way or a setting like that reads only new entries.
or a filter that ensures not to read the archived files, but only the active”ones

Comment: From its configuration, it doesn't look like that it has something like that. Alternatively, you can check the [tail](https://docs.fluentd.org/input/tail) input plugin.

Comment: Also, you should [open an issue](https://github.com/fluent-plugin-systemd/fluent-plugin-systemd/issues/new/choose) for the systemd input plugin with all the details.

Comment: I am getting logs now but have a problem with filter: i need to create new fileds with values depending on an existing field For eg, i want a new field by name 'severity' and the values should be extracted from the field 'LOGINFO'. `code`<filter docker>
  @type record_transformer  enable_ruby true
  <record>   SEVERITY ${record["LOGINFO"].gsub(/^*(\w*)\ 1\ -*/)} 
  </record>  
</filter>`code`
 When i redeploy with this i get errors Exception emitting record: undefined method `to_msgpack' 
 emit transaction failed: error_class=NoMethodError error="undefined method `to_msgpack'

Comment: Share the complete log.

Comment: #0 Exception emitting record: undefined method `to_msgpack' for #<Enumerator:0x00007ff786fecb28>
2021-03-31 09:51:14 +0000 [warn]: #0 emit transaction failed: error_class=NoMethodError error="undefined method `to_msgpack' for #<Enumerator:0x00007ff786b913f8>" location="/fluentd/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/fluentd-1.12.0/lib/fluent/event.rb:60:in `write'" tag="docker"
  2021-03-31 09:51:14 +0000 [warn]: #0 suppressed same stacktrace

Comment: its full of this message continuously

Comment: Screenshot added to post

Comment: Looks like your message is ill-formed. Look at the discussion at this GitHub issue: https://github.com/fluent/fluentd/issues/2072.

Comment: I had gone through that same earlier and now again but couldnt find asolution to this issue unfortunately. is there anything i need to change in the filter

Comment: You need to verify the emitted record. That contains something which is not parsable/serializable by msgpack module.

Comment: Everything works now; with the filter record transformer and read_from_head false. Thanks

Comment: That's good. What was the issue?